# Office 365 Work with an External SAML Identity gives error: 800478A1

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, office365

I have configured Azure AD and federated the domain.

I have followed the [MSDN guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn641269.aspx) on using a SAML 2.0 IdP to implement SSO and [this blog](http://www.viewds.com/blog/making-office-365-work-with-an-external-saml-identity-provider.html).

I could successfully redirect to my custom IdP page. The IDP sends a SAML token to "**login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf**". But it gives an error with code `800478A1`.

Please let me know what went wrong. I have copied the SAML response below for reference.

```xml
<saml2p:Response
Destination="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf"
ID="id66864f3b430546b1a10e488579ea0ba1"
Version="2.0"
IssueInstant="2016-05-13T01:53:56Z"
Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
InResponseTo="_049917a6-1183-42fd-a190-1d2cbaf9b144"
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://localhost:52071/</saml2:Issuer>
<saml2p:Status><saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></saml2p:Status>
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="_a1efef91-62e4-4ff5-93c1-9b456603f5d4" IssueInstant="2016-05-13T01:53:56Z">
    <saml2:Issuer>http://localhost:52071/Metadata</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">johndoe@example.com</saml2:NameID>
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:Oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2016-05-13T02:13:56Z" Recipient="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf" InResponseTo="_049917a6-1183-42fd-a190-1d2cbaf9b144"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml2:Subject>
    <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2016-05-13T01:55:56Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-05-13T02:15:56Z">
        <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml2:Audience>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml2:Audience>
        </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml2:Conditions>
    <saml2:AttributeStatement>
        <saml2:Attribute Name="IDPEmail">
            <saml2:AttributeValue>johndoe@example.com</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
    </saml2:AttributeStatement>
    <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-05-13T01:53:56Z" SessionIndex="42">
        <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
        </saml2:AuthnContext>
    </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="#id66864f3b430546b1a10e488579ea0ba1">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>ynB0J1UwKJ9396uOkbMajyi2k8s=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>*** redacted ***</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>*** redacted ***</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</saml2:Assertion>
```

Comment: have you tried to close all tabs and browser and sign in again(If you use the chrome, you can try to test it in new incognito window)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems you are passing user's email in NameID in subject field. Is it possible that your IDP send immutable iD or objectguid in sam response in NAmeID field.

Comment: This could have been a comment.
Read more about when to post an answer or comment over [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment).